# FTP issue with Azure VM

Tags: ftp, windows-server-2012, azure

I am trying to run a working FTP script on my Azure VM with Server2012.

All firewalls are off for this test.
Port20/21 is an open endpoint.

```
OPEN ftp.domain.co.uk
user
password
cd current
binary hash
prompt n
quote pasv
MGET *.*
QUIT
```

Response:

```
ftp> OPEN ftp.domain.co.uk
Connected to ftp.domain.co.uk.
220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
220-You are user number 2 of 50 allowed.
220-Local time is now 15:15. Server port: 21.
220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
220 You will be disconnected after 3 minutes of inactivity.
User (ftp.domain.co.uk:(none)):
331 User xxxxxxx OK. Password required

230-User xxxxxxxxx has group access to:  ftpgroup
230-OK. Current directory is /
230-All usage is logged for security and statistical analysis purposes.
230 Do not exceed one download set per 10 minute interval.
ftp> cd current
250 OK. Current directory is /current
ftp> binary hash
200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary
ftp> prompt n
Interactive mode Off .
ftp> quote pasv
227 Entering Passive Mode (85,17,xx,xxx,197,86)
ftp> MGET *.*
I won't open a connection to 10.140.x.xx (only to 168.63.xxx.xxx)
200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary
Cannot find list of remote files.
ftp> QUIT
221-Goodbye. You uploaded 0 and downloaded 0 kbytes.
221 Logout.
```

As you can see, it has a problem at the MGET command.

Ive tried a active command with PORT xx,xx,xxx,xxx,xx,xx but i get an Invalid command after that line from the FTP client.

Filezilla connects ok via port 21.

Comment: Did you really obscure the IP addresses of well-known public sites? That seems unnecessary and unhelpful.

Comment: just what I normally do , i didnt think the actually address was relevant in this example.

Comment: @DanSewell did you create endpoints for your passive port range?

Comment: no, because You can only create upto 25 endpoints in total, rather than ranges.

Comment: @DanSewell Right, but then you need to limit your passive port range to match that. Without endpoints passive will not work as it more or less acts as a firewall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seems the windows FTP does not do passive ftp properly, so I ended up writing my own ftp program in c# forcing passive mode. This is fine.

Comment: How? Can I have the code? Have a similar, potentially the same, problem.